# How to enumerate interface keys to make new interface that the value is depend on the key

Tags: typescript

How to iterate interface keys to make new interface that the value is depend on the key.

```
type IParse<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends string ? K : never]: string // How to make if K === 'a' the type should be number
}

interface X {
    a: number
    b: string
    c: string[]
    d: number[]
}

type Result = IParse<X>

// Actual result

interface Actual {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
    d: string
}

// Expected result

interface Expected {
    a: number
    b: string
    c: string
    d: string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgCgQwE4GcIB4AqA+KBeKAbwCgBIAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMykygRSmogAPYBDoATPimBJ6AcygB+flABcUOhABuEJAF01UmXXkB6E1AASrAO5RgrKAFsEzWp2p5PUAOQJvdgAtoUEgoFADWAFcAGzEoACNoOkjHRKRiAF9iYnoRJHYEAGNoAA0iMgQ1ZNSdMniDaTkyQoajWXJdMjEqlLSOzOyQ6AAlCBQY4HxYRFQMEuxssygAQULgSIRoqCQxiezcnQLilbWNrZIoS55WpquEm+NiO5awxse77te2geIlgFFBJA1hA4jtxtFgPs6HkjtAAUCRHELldKuperU7vUvrcri9DDjLp98Y8skA)

Comment: Just use a mapped type [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/w29g8W).  You don't need to remap keys (you want the same keys, right?). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - I assumed that was to weed out Symbols and numbers, but assumptions are dangerous. :-)

Comment: Probably the key remapping should be removed from the question and possibly replaced with `type Parse<T> = { [K in keyof T]: string }`.  Unless there's some reason why it needs to be there *for the question* (and not just for the user's underlying use case), in which case the example should show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a conditional to the value portion of what you have:

```typescript
type IParse<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends string ? K : never]: 
        K extends "a" ? number : string; // <======================
};

interface X {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string[];
    d: number[];
}

type Result = IParse<X>;
//   ^? -- type Result = {a: number; b: string; c: string; d: string; }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgCgQwE4GcIB4AqA+KBeKAbwCgBIAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMykygRSmogAPYBDoATPimBJ6AcygB+flABcUOhABuEJAF01xKEeNGBw0RKgAiBFcXqArgFsARjtVQpMurIDcxAF9-YnoRJHYEAGNoAA0iMgQ1Omc3JH9SFzUvOXTIrOk5cl10sSSUnSL-AOJiUEgoACUIFAcAG2B8WERUDBjsfwB6AeMAPQViIA)